# Scale a vector until it reaches a certain bound

Tags: python

I got a two points A and B with their respective x and y coordinates. Point B determines the direction of the vector AB, and I know that `-10^9 <= x,y <= 10^9`. My goal is to scale that vector until the x or y coordinate of B hit either bound. Basically I need the vector AB, where B is moved to the edge without changing the direction. In practice this should represent a linear flight path of an object.

How can this easily be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the intersection of the line that contains AB with the line $x=10^9$.  This is easy.

Do the same for the line AB and the line $x=-10^9$, and for AB and $y=10^9$, and for $AB$ and $y=-10^9$.  Now you should be able to take it from there.